# Custom list data doesn't appear consistent in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: list

I have a list that seems to be acting oddly.

The list has 5 custom columns.  2 columns are text fields, the others are lookup fields.

When I view the list I see data in all 5 columns.  When I edit a pre-existing item I see data only in the Title field.

When I add a new item I can add data to all columns.  However, once I am back viewing the list view I only see the Title field data for this new item (pre-existing items still show as mentioned above).  When I edit this new item I then can see all the data I originally entered.

Does anyone have any idea of what might be happening?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this? If yes, could you post the answer?

Comment: Can you please move your comment to an answer? This way, you can mark it as the correct answer and allow other people to contribute. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple columns with the same label that aren't displayed in the same views/forms. Once we found that out we removed the unnecessary columns and made sure all columns were viewable in the views/forms.